# log4j Points to the Wrong Back Slash Log Path

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to deploy an application on WebLogic 9 and the console log keep throwing this error:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs\sd.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:177)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:272)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:151)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:247)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:123)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:87)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:645)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:603)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:500)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:406)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:432)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:460)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:94)
    at com.sherwin.sd.web.filter.RedirectFilter.logger(RedirectFilter.java:253)
    at com.sherwin.sd.web.filter.RedirectFilter.init(RedirectFilter.java:113)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:309)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:88)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1618)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2761)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:889)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:333)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:635)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:358)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:52)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:186)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:254)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:239)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [R].
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs\sd.log (The system cannot find the
>   path specified)

I can see that it points to the back slash path instead of the correct forward slash. After that I've checked back to the log4j.properties and make sure the path for the logs/sd.log is correct, the folder and log file is in there too:

[image]

However, it still throws me path not found error due to the back slash. What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired to give `sd.log` a absolute path (`/logs/sd.log`) and it doesn't work. Finally I simply changed the **`log4j.appender.R.File`** path to `sd.log` and `FileNotFoundException` error gone away.